# Significato di "lisciaia" e "liscia"

Tags: word-meaning, regional, vocabulary

Nel libro *Verde acqua* di Marisa Madieri (pubblicato da Einaudi) ho letto queste frasi:

> "Mentre sorseggiava il solito caffè in cucina, gli è caduto lo sguardo sulla mia lavatrice in funzione e, scuotendo il capo, l'ha definita l'invenzione piú utile del secolo per l'enorme risparmio di fatica ch'essa comporta. Di ***«liscie»*** ne aveva fatte tante in vita sua."
>
> "La mamma scaldava pazientemente dei pentoloni d'acqua, li versava fumanti in una grande mastella nello sgabuzzino e lasciava la roba a mollo per una notte con la lisciva. L'indomani portava il tutto nella ***lisciaia*** comune, strofinava a lungo col sapone, curva sulla vasca di cemento, e sciacquava con l'acqua gelida."

Il contesto rende chiaro che le parole "liscia" e "lisciaia" hanno a che vedere col bucato, ma cosa significano esattamente?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Credo che siano termini parzialmente o totalmente dialettali (potrei però sbagliarmi).

La **lisciaia** è una stanza in cui si fa il bucato (simile al "safareig" che sicuramente conosci). Un altro termine è **lavatoio**. 
Ormai nelle case moderne non esiste più, o si è trasformato in un ripostiglio generico e multiuso.

Sulla **liscia**, credo che sia una versione dialettale friulana dell'italiano **liscivia** ("lleixiu"), che è una sostanza ottenuta dalla bollitura della cenere e che si usava per togliere le macchie dai panni prima di lavarli. Suppongo che per estensione, "fare la liscia" potesse significare appunto "fare il bucato" o quantomeno "applicare la liscia al bucato".
In tutti i casi, attività che sono state interamente sostituite dalla lavatrice.

Ho trovato [questo link](http://dizionario-goriziano-italiano.blogspot.com.es/p/jkl.html#Liscia) che sembra confermare che si tratta di un termine dialettale.

Comment: Hai ragione: "liscivia" è "lleixiu" in catalano.